# Can I say "I let my nails painted?"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "I let my nails painted"

or should it be : "I let my nails be painted"

thanks

Comment: If you’re from a German-speaking country, it’s quite likely that you’re looking for “I *had* my nails painted” (Ich habe mir die Nägel lackieren *lassen*)

Answer (score 2):

It should be "I let my nails be painted" as 'be' here is the helping verb. Thus, it can not be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to say: "I let my nails be painted", as this is the passive voice.

It's more common, however, to simply say, "I get my nails done".

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.

The version you probably intend is the second: *you let your nails **be** painted*.

> **let1** *verb*
>   1 (with object and infinitive) Not prevent or forbid; allow.
>   ‘my boss let me leave early’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let)

In the other version, you think of your nails as real estate (e.g. a house), which you rented out in a painted state (*you let your nails painted*). This is a similar construction to '*you left your door unlocked*'.

> **let1** *verb*
>   3 British (with object) Allow someone to have the use of (a room or property) in return for regular payments.
>   ‘she let the flat to a tenant’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let)

Note that one doesn't normally *let* one's nails in the sense of definition 3 above (unless perhaps as a figure of speech in a context such as working professionally as a [hand model](https://www.wikihow.com/Become-a-Hand-Model)), but the construction passes the low bar of grammatical correctness.

Comment: "I let my nails painted," is not correct.  It means nothing.

Comment: @EllieK It would be a figurative expression, as my answer makes clear ("*you think of your nails as real estate*").

Comment: Sorry but no.  You cannot let your nails in the same way you let an apartment.  Your figurative expression does not work.  It's a construct entirely of your own making and is not supported by the language or its usage.

Comment: @EllieK The OP asked "Is it correct ...", which I take to be asking whether it's grammatical - not necessarily idiomatic. My answer points out that both are grammatically correct, and that one version was more likely to be the one the OP intended.

Comment: @EllieK I feel that my answer is sufficiently backed up by relevant references that it can stand the test of scrutiny. But thank you for explaining your objection. I appreciate the opportunity to discuss our use of language and have edited my answer to take your point into consideration.

Comment: The definition clearly states  "a room or property".  The sentence "She let her nails painted."  Fails that test.  I will give you that it is grammatically correct -- it does take an object.  But, as I said, it has no meaning.  And it would need a comma.  She let her nails, painted.

Comment: @EllieK 'I let the room furnished' certainly does not require a comma (though one is possible). But 'I let my nails painted' is as grammatical as 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously'. And just about as unacceptable on grounds of (lack of) idiomaticity / meaningfulness.